# compare string column with other column by row wise

Tags: r

I have a data frame as below,how to compare values from 2 columns.i.e row 1 has common string("SZY")in both col a & b and extra in string in col a (ABC)
for row 5 common string is "BNM" and extra strings in both col a and b.

```
a=c("ABC,SZY","XYZ",NA,NA,"ABC,BNM,JKL","DEF","XCV")
b=c("SZY","XYZ,IOP","QWE",NA,"BNM,JKL,STU","DEF","HJK")
df = data.frame(a,b)
```

output should be as follows

```
output = c("COMMON+column_a","COMMON+column_b","DIFFERENT",NA,"COMMON+column_a+column_b","COMMON","DIFFERENT")
df = cbind(df,output)
```

Comment: Is this what your actual output would look like? Or there would be strings replacing them?

Comment: Thanks@Ronak, no other strings replacing the output. the column "output" is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one in base R,

```
vapply(strsplit(do.call(paste, df), " |,"), function(x) 
                               toString(unique(x[x != 'NA'])), character(1L))

#[1] "ABC, SZY"    "XYZ, IOP"    "QWE"    ""    "ABC, BNM, JKL, STU" "DEF"   "XCV, HJK"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R `apply` we can split the strings on comma, delete `NA` entries, keep only `unique` values convert them to comma separated string again.

```
df$output <- apply(df, 1, function(x) 
                  toString(unique(na.omit(unlist(strsplit(x, ","))))))

df
#            a           b             output
#1     ABC,SZY         SZY           ABC, SZY
#2         XYZ     XYZ,IOP           XYZ, IOP
#3        <NA>         QWE                QWE
#4        <NA>        <NA>                   
#5 ABC,BNM,JKL BNM,JKL,STU ABC, BNM, JKL, STU
#6         DEF         DEF                DEF
#7         XCV         HJK           XCV, HJK
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `cSplit` where we split the dataset columns into 'long' format at the delimiter `,` after creating a row names columns.  Then grouped by 'rn', get the `union` of the column elements with `Reduce` and assign that column as 'output' in the original dataset

```
library(data.table)
library(splitstackshape)
df$output <- cSplit(setDT(df, keep.rownames = TRUE), c("a", "b"), ",", 
      "long")[, toString(Reduce(union, lapply(.SD, na.omit))), rn]$V1
df
#   rn           a           b             output
#1:  1     ABC,SZY         SZY           ABC, SZY
#2:  2         XYZ     XYZ,IOP           XYZ, IOP
#3:  3        <NA>         QWE                QWE
#4:  4        <NA>        <NA>                   
#5:  5 ABC,BNM,JKL BNM,JKL,STU ABC, BNM, JKL, STU
#6:  6         DEF         DEF                DEF
#7:  7         XCV         HJK           XCV, HJK
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, we `gather` the data into 'long' format after creating a row names column, separate the rows of 'val' at the delimiter `,`, replace the NA elements with `,`, get the `distinct` rows based on 'rn' and 'val' column, paste the strings together (`str_c`) grouped by 'rn' and bind the column 'output' with the original dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
rownames_to_column(df, 'rn') %>% 
   gather(key, val, -rn) %>% 
   separate_rows(val) %>%
   mutate(val = replace_na(val, "")) %>%
   distinct(rn, val) %>%
   group_by(rn) %>% 
   summarise(val = str_c(val, collapse=",")) %>% 
   select(-rn) %>% 
   bind_cols(df, .)
```

---

Or with `base R`, we split the columns with `strsplit` at the delimiter `,`, get the `union` of the `list` elements using `Map` and `paste` it into a single string, `unlist` the `list` into a `vector` and assign it to create the 'output' column

```
df$output <- unlist(do.call(Map, c(f = function(...) 
        toString(union(...)), unname(lapply(df, strsplit, ",")))))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(a = c("ABC,SZY", "XYZ", NA, NA, "ABC,BNM,JKL", 
"DEF", "XCV"), b = c("SZY", "XYZ,IOP", "QWE", NA, "BNM,JKL,STU", 
"DEF", "HJK")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```